# Tap-and-hold on a day required to activate full calendar day click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I am using **fullcalendar** jquery plugin on my site. It works perfectly on my laptop. But on **mobile** devices when I tap on a day in month view, the modal which is meant to get information about the event user wants to create (start time, end time , event title) doesn't fire up immediately, instead I have to **tap and hold** on the **day** for sometime for the **modal to appear**, same thing happens when I have to create a multi day event, ie. I have to tap and hold on the first day and then after some time the day gets selected and I can move my finger ahead to select more days. Is there any way to **fire these events immediately when I tap on the day** or maybe reduce the time delay for a smoother experience? Maybe some suggestions? (The code is quite large so I am not adding any snippet but if it will help I could add the fullCalendar options.) 
 Any advice will be greatly appreciated!! Thank You!!!

Comment: I think with the tap-and-hold requirement the intention is to distinguish between the "select" callback and the "dayClick" or "eventClick" callbacks which could be the other consequence of tapping on an area of the calendar. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/Touch_Support/ suggests you can use the longPressDelay option to control the delay.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This really helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `touchstart`

```
$(document).on('touchstart', '.fc-day', function(e){
  //..
});
```

to support `click` and `touchstart` you can do this:

```
var bindEvent = (document.ontouchstart!==null) ? 'click' : 'touchstart';

$(document).on(bindEvent, '.fc-day', function(e){
  //..
});
```